# What would be a good, user-friendly way to filter strings using concise, logical rules?

Tags: string, list, filter

I have a list of strings and I want to filter them using some rules. Any strings passing the filtering get appended to a new list of strings. An example rule could be to pass a string if it contains X *or* if it contains Y *and* Z. I know that I can code this stuff using Python `if` statements and so on, but is there a more concise, user-friendly way of doing this kind of filtering? Is there some (perhaps SQL-like) language for doing things like this?

```
# Accept or filter specified datasets.
filterDatasets = False   
if filterDatasets:
    # Filter specified datasets.
    datasets = []
    # Cycle over all datasets specified.
    logger.info('filtering specified datasets')
    for dataset in datasetsSpecified:
        # If data was specified, then skip a specified dataset if its name
        # does not contain "data12" or "merge". If data was not specified,
        # then skip a specified dataset if its name does not contain "mc12".
        if isData:
            requiredSubstrings = [
                #'data12',
                'Egamma',
                'Muons',
                #'merge',
            ]
            for substring in requiredSubstrings:
                if substring not in dataset:
                    logger.debug("substring {substring} not in dataset name {dataset}".format(substring = substring, dataset = dataset))
                    continue
                else:
                    datasets.append(dataset)                
        else:
            requiredSubstrings = [
                'mc12'
            ]
            for substring in requiredSubstrings:
                if substring not in dataset:
                    logger.debug("substring {substring} not in dataset name {dataset}".format(substring = substring, dataset = dataset))
                    continue
                else:
                    datasets.append(dataset)
        excludedSubstrings = [
            '#'
        ]
        for substring in excludedSubstrings:
            if substring in dataset:
                logger.debug("substring {substring} in dataset name {dataset}".format(substring = substring, dataset = dataset))
                continue
else:
    datasets = datasetsSpecified
logger.info('datasets accepted: {datasets}'.format(datasets = datasets))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd consider regular expressions the "SQL" of text strings - almost any text processing you can think of can be done:

[http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=hello|[a-z]%2Bbye](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=hello|%5ba-z%5d%2Bbye)

Examples of what matches this:

- hello
- goodbye
- hellobye
- bbye

Examples of what does not match this:

- hell
- ello
- bye
- goodby

Just run each item in the list through the regular expression and keep it if it is a match.

Not a heavy Python user myself (only occasional) but according to the documentation there is support for them:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'll give regex a try in Python (though I'm not sure how user-friendly others are likely to figure it is).